# Como otimizar melhor o script de conexão e listagem de informações do MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Como otimizar melhor o script de conexão e listagem de informações do `MySQL`? Pois verifico em minhas pesquisas diversas formas de se fazer isso, mas não sei se esta aqui é uma prática correta tanto de conexão com banco de dados quanto para listar informações do `MySQL`.

**conexão.php**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "guaraparivirtual");
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include ("conexao.php"); ?>

<?php

$seleciona=mysqli_query($con,"select * from noticias");
while($campo=mysqli_fetch_array($seleciona)){
?>

<?php echo $campo["Titulo"]."</br>"; ?>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: `select id, titulo from noticias` e imprime um link com o codigo(id) da noticia e o título, `<a href=\"noticia/$campo["id"]\" target="_blank">$campo["titulo"]</a><br/>`, a menos que o teu título não contenha caracteres especiais. Atenção a tag *<br>*.

Comment: Definir senhas direto no código, da maneira que está no `conexao.php` não é ideal, existem outras formas, [falei especificamente sobre uma das outras formas aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/216285/15089). Sobre a otimização da query a resposta do @Leo Caracciolo menciona uma das melhorias que podem ser feitas, que é evitar usar o `*`.

Answer (score 2):

Faça select somente das colunas que interessam para poupar recursos do servidor e agilizar sua pesquisa, no seu caso a coluna `titulo`

Mais elegante e fácil de ser lido.

```
<?php 
   include ("conexao.php");
   $seleciona=mysqli_query($con,"select titulo from noticias");
     while($campo=mysqli_fetch_array($seleciona))
     {
       echo $campo["Titulo"]."</br>"; ?>
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de utilizar `SELECT * FROM`, você pode utilizar `SELECT titulo FROM noticias`, não tem porque pegar todos os campos, sendo que só ira utilizar o titulo e etc. Dessa maneira a pesquisa será mais rapida.
Também lhe aconselho a utilizar PDO

```
<?php
try {
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname= guaraparivirtual', 'root', '');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>


$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT titulo FROM noticias");
$ln = $sql->fetchObject();

echo $ln->titulo;
```

mas independente do que usar, sempre, que não for utilizar todos os campos da tabela, selecione apenas os que for usar.ç